# Does Collections.shuffle() randomize list in place?

Tags: java, random

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
...
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

shuffle return void, does that mean the parameter 'list' is changed internally, i.e. after the call, 'list' is already randomized? This sounds like a good way to get a random sample of a collection. Normally, I don't have to write my own randomize function. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes. It's in place. Correct.

Comment: Yes, The approach works independent and more efficient then random function. The shuffle is random as the algorithm by selecting uniformly an element which has not been selected. For example if the element at position 2 is selected it can be exchanged with all elements at position 2 until position n-1 (as the list /array has 0 - n-1 positions).

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `shuffle` method of `Collections` indeed shuffles the `ArrayList` **in place**, that also holds for any other `Collection` you pass to the method. That is also the case for many other methods there, like `sort`.

---

From the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-):

> This implementation traverses the list backwards, from the last element up to the second, repeatedly swapping a randomly selected element into the "current position". Elements are randomly selected from the portion of the list that runs from the first element to the current position, inclusive.

And also, very important:

> If the specified list does not implement the RandomAccess interface and is large, this implementation dumps the specified list into an array before shuffling it, and dumps the shuffled array back into the list.

This would, for example, be the case for a `LinkedList`.

There is also a variant that takes a `Random` object, if you want to have more control over the **seeding** for example, also see the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-java.util.Random-).

---

To answer your last question, yes it is a good idea to use that method if you want to have a random permutation of a given collection. The implementation is pretty efficient. However for some special collections you could write a more efficient method, if that is really necessary.

For this I'd recommend to take a look at the implementation of `Collections#shuffle` as seen [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.shuffle%28java.util.List%2Cjava.util.Random%29).